# How to expand this expression: $\frac{z}{2}<|y|<z$, is it correct to expand it as following: $-z<-\frac{z}{2}<y<\frac{z}{2}<z$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

How to express this expression 
$\frac{z}{2}<|y|<z$.

Is it correct to expand it as following

$-z<-\frac{z}{2}<y<\frac{z}{2}<z$

Comment: Not quite. I'm assuming you have $z > 0$. In that case, note that $y=0$ satisfies your expansion, but does not satisfy the original.

Comment: What expansion do you mean? And how is Taylor's expansion involved in this?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $z > \vert y \vert \geq 0$. So we must have $z>0$ and $\vert y \vert > 0$. Note that $y = 0$ would imply $z$ is both positive and negative ... oops! For $y>0$, you have
$$\frac{z}{2} < y < z$$
and for $y < 0$ you have
$$ \frac{z}{2} < -y < z \implies \frac{-z}{2} > y > -z.$$ 
This shows that $y$ lies in
$$\left(-z, \frac{-z}{2}\right) \cup \left(\frac{z}{2}, z \right)$$ 
So you need two statements to expand, and you would say
$$-z<y<-\frac{z}{2}<0 \, \text{ or } \, 0<\frac{z}{2} < y < z.$$